# mysql error table cannot be used in global order clause

Tags: mysql, join, union

```
(SELECT dtable.* FROM app_detailsvvv as dtable INNER JOIN new_apps ON 
new_apps.trackId=dtable.trackId WHERE primaryGenreName='Games' AND composed='1' AND
new_apps.top>0) UNION (SELECT * FROM app_detailsvvv as dtable WHERE
primaryGenreName='Games') ORDER BY new_apps.top ASC, trackName ASC LIMIT 12
```

with that query I get this error:

```
#1250 - Table 'new_apps' from one of the SELECTs cannot be used in global ORDER clause
```

new_apps is not used in the second query, the idea is to get first by top rank from the same table that has also listed the id in new_apps table

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As docs [says](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/union.html)

> This kind of ORDER BY cannot use column references that include a table name (that is, names in tbl_name.col_name format). Instead, provide a column alias in the first SELECT statement and refer to the alias in the ORDER BY.

So rewrite it like this

```
(
    SELECT dtable.*, new_apps.top as t1
    FROM app_detailsvvv as dtable
    INNER JOIN new_apps ON new_apps.trackId=dtable.trackId
    WHERE primaryGenreName='Games' AND composed='1' AND new_apps.top > 0
)
UNION
(
    SELECT *, 0
    FROM app_detailsvvv as dtable
    WHERE primaryGenreName='Games'
)
ORDER BY t1 ASC, trackName ASC
LIMIT 12
```

Comment: Seems like the solution, no duplicates would be grabbed considered both are getting selected from app_detailsvvv, need to group by trackId ?

Comment: If you don't want duplicates you can surround it with another `SELECT` with `GROUP BY trackId`